# How to Prevent Excel from Removing Formula from Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating Excel files from a Web App (C#).

Some cells have formulas and being written properly tested by writing as texts. However, when the files are opened, a dialog box with Yes/No is displayed saying something like below:

[image]

When Yes is selected, you see the info dialog as below saying the formula were removed.:

[image]

Anyone knows how to prevent Excel from doing his?

```
private static void AppendFormulaeCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, ref 
OpenXmlWriter writer)
{     
     CellFormula cellFormula = new CellFormula("SUM(S11:S13");
     cellFormula.CalculateCell = true;
        
     //  Add a new Excel Cell to our Row 
     writer.WriteElement(new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(cellStringValue), CellReference = 
     cellReference, DataType = CellValues.Number, CellFormula = cellFormula });
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't an Excel formula need to start with a `=` sign? Yours doesn't. Also, what do you see when you view the log file that lists the repairs? That should give you information about the problem that we cannot see from your screenshots.

Comment: Hello teylyn, the log has just two lines - basically same thing what we see on the screen. Like:                                                                     <removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part</removedRecord><removedRecord>Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part</removedRecord> . Also the "=" sign is not needed as when you write the Excel file, the equal will be appended as it's a formula.

Comment: In that case you may want to add more info about how you create the workbook. "From a Web App (C#)"  does not help much. Also tag with something other than Excel, because such a formula works fine in Excel and the problem only comes up when you generate the workbook with code, so the problem must be with how the file is generated, especially if it is repeatable and not a one-off fluke due to workbook corruption.

Comment: After reading your comment to the other answer: you have a problem with a formula that gets removed when Excel opens the file and you are looking for help, but you don't post the formula you're actually using. Instead, you post a simple sum(). How on earth would that help us figure out what is wrong with the formula you're using?  If you've made a mistake in the actual Excel formula in your code, then THAT may very well be the reason that Excel removes it as unreadable content, and posting a simple Sum() in its stead is ... ehm ... not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Di you try closing properly the formula's parenthesis after S13?

```
CellFormula cellFormula = new CellFormula("SUM(S11:S13)");
```

Also, I think you have to clear the cell attributes before writing to it

Comment: Hello JMB, that's in fact not the real formula, just used as an example and when doing that - I goofed in not closing it with the closing parenthesis. Thanks for the response. I will look into clearing the cell attributes.